# why cache folder on pm2 next node application is growing too big?

Tags: node.js, caching, next.js, pm2

I have a application react.js running with next/node/pm2 and the folder app/.next/cache/images is growing too big. Now it has 22gb.
My application serves a lot of imagens but it pull the images from cloud-front so it should not be caching all imagens on the application server side.
How can I manage to not have images cached on the pm2 app server?

I'm looking for alternatives to setup my pm2 app to not keep cache of any image but no success.

Comment: According to this [GH issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31395#discussioncomment-1643499), it's safe to delete the `.next/cache` folder as it's not needed for production.